# Django FileResponse crashes with large files

Tags: python, django, django-views, nginx-reverse-proxy, daphne

...I have a Django application with a lot of data and a MariaDB database running on a Raspberry Pi (OS = Debian 12). The application uses Daphne as Webserver because there are also Django Channels components in there (Websocket). Now I want to implement a backup feature, that automatically dumps the database, zips together the dump with the other data files and has the browser automatically download the ZIP-file. So I made a view for the download:

```
def downbackup(request): 
  if request.user.is_superuser:
    filename = '../temp/backup/backup.zip'
    sourcefile = open(filename, 'rb')
    return FileResponse(sourcefile)
  else:
    return(HttpResponse('No Access.'))
```

That view is called from the relevant template via url and verything is fine. Until we meet large files in real live. In this case (filesize around 6 GB) Daphne immediatly stops operation, and the Raspi crashes so deep that I have to switch power on and of. Also, in Monitorix I see huge memory consumption spikes after these crashes. But there is no error message in the Daphne logs, in the Django logs (incl. debug-setting) nor in the journalctl. Nginx (the reverse proxy) reports an uplink timeout (504). I think I learned from the Django documentation the FileResponse buffers the file to avoid memory consumption, but something must be wrong here. Any ideas, recommendations?

Comment: I would strongly advise *not* to use Django as a file server, it is not intended to use that way. Typically nginx is used for example with an `X-Accl-Redirect` such that Django essentially says where the file is, and nginx, can then return the file in a manner that only nginx provides the file when an `X-Accl-Redirect` is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise *not* to use Django as a file server, it is not intended to use that way. Typically nginx is used for example with an [**`X-Accel-Redirect`** <sup>[nginx-doc]</sup>](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) such that Django essentially says where the file is, and nginx, can then return the file in a manner that only nginx provides the file when an `X-Accel-Redirect` is present.

So essentially you work with:

```
def downbackup(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=backup.zip'
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected/temp/backup/backup.zip'
        return response
    else:
        return HttpResponse('No Access.')
```

and then the nginx server thus serves a *protected* path with:

```
location /protected/ {
  internal;
  alias   /path/one/above/tmp/;
}
```

this will not only make sure there are no problems with nginx buffering and steaming, but can also result in the nginx caching certain files and thus boosting efficiency of the webserver.

The `internal` keyword in the `/protected/` config means that you can not make requests from outside to this path. So a person can not visit `/protected/temp/backup/backup.zip`, it can only be used for internal communication in nginx with the "sub-servers".

Comment: Great! I only had to add one slash in the Nginx-config to get it running on my Raspi:
alias   /path/one/above/tmp/;

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's `StreamingHttpResponse` instead of `FileResponse` to efficiently handle large files.

```py
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
import os

def download_large_file(request):
    # Path to the large file
    file_path = '/path/to/your/large/file'

    def file_iterator(file_path, chunk_size=8192):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                yield chunk

    response = StreamingHttpResponse(file_iterator(file_path))
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    return response
```

Comment: The `FileResponse` is already a `StreamingHttpResponse`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects